# How can I do a similar prompt using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to programming, and I need your help. 
How can I do a similar prompt using Material UI 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lVMT.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like a tooltip you can find it here
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tooltip/#main-content